# Graph API cannot use $search

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Powershell to call Graph API.

I have no problem in using filter and contains to search for messages with a particular subject as follows:

```
$upn = 'john.doe@a.com.au'
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$upn/messages?filter=contains(subject,'INC0343928')&count=true"
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($ConnectGraph.access_token)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $api -Method Get
```

I am really exhausted trying to find out why I cannot $Search to perform the same task.
The following $search will just return all the messages.

```
$upn = 'john.doe@a.com.au'
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$upn/messages?$search='subject:INC0432318'"
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($ConnectGraph.access_token)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $api -Method Get
```

I have posted on Microsoft Q&A but they are not able to help me.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you need `$search` to show up in the URL of the request you need to escape the dollar sign, otherwise it will be treated as a variable by PowerShell.

```
$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$upn/messages?`$search='subject:INC0432318'"
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense Gerald.  
However, I got a **(400) bad request** when I ran it like below.  
Any thoughts?  


$api = "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/$upn/messages?`$search='subject:INC0432318'"
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($ConnectGraph.access_token)"} -ContentType application/json -Uri $api -Method Get
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: This works - **$api = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/users/john.doe@a.com.au/messages?$search="subject:INC0343928"'**